# Is there a way to make functions in PHP synchronized without using threads

Tags: php, synchronization, data-synchronization

Is there a way to make functions in PHP synchronized so that when two or more users access the same link at the same time i need to access the function which includes insertion of order no into table and it has to happen one by one i am not using threads

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, I suggest you rewise it to make your question more clear.

Comment: Apart from that: _it might be_ that what you are looking for is a cache where different requests can read half finished results from which are prepared only once or only after an alteration.

Comment: You realise that each user request is running in its own thread? The Webserver handles this.... but if you're inserting data from two users concurrently into a database, then each order should be assigned a unique primary key so if you have an autoincrement column on your database table for pk

Comment: I got it i used flock function for this. [link]http://us3.php.net/flock